# Python : Getting account data from SQL, updating it and setting into global variable in script

Tags: python

I'm building simple Account password change script and while I was doing it, I saw some errors that after changing the password, the global variable doesn't change. Do I need to create an class or global variable, to always get latest information from SQL Database as `Account_ID, Account_Password.`
I was using this, but it's only for first time, the variables doesn't update if  they would be used later.

```
try:
                acc_username = input("* Please enter your username: ")
                acc_password = getpass.getpass("* Please enter your password: ")
                connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                                            password="postgres",
                                            host="127.0.0.1",
                                            port="5432",
                                            database="postgres")
                cursor = connection.cursor()
                postgreSQL_select_Query = "select * from admins WHERE username=('%s') AND password = ('%s')" % (acc_username, acc_password)
                cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query) # PALEIST KOMANDA
                adminu_data = cursor.fetchall()  # READ DATA
                # IF NON EXIST'S
                if not adminu_data:
                    os.system('cls')
                    print("* Wrong password or username")
                    time.sleep(5) 
                    os.system('cls')
                    continue
                else:
                    for row in adminu_data:
                        # ADMIN INFO
                        global Admin_Id
                        Admin_ID = row[0]

                        global Admin_Username
                        Admin_Username = row[1]

                        global Admin_Password
                        Admin_Password = row[2]

                        global Admin_Email
                        Admin_Email = row[3]

                        print("* You're logged in as", Admin_Username)
                        time.sleep(3)
                        os.system('cls')
```

After  getting the global variables they will be used somewhere and they will be working, but if I would change the account password in database I would get same old results or I would need to reload the application to get the new  results.

Comment: what do you mean by "variables not updated" ? what does the print statement print ?

Comment: The print statement prints old results.

Comment: Also print your row and see if the row is correct.